# Getting blocked by website while attempting BeautifulSoup scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

trying to scrape a site using beautiful soup:

```
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})

html = 'https://www.goodrx.com/classes'
webpage = requests.get(html,headers=headers)
content = webpage.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True):

    print ("Found the URL:",a['href'])
```

It is returning the following result:

Found the URL: https://www.perimeterx.com/whywasiblocked

What am I missing to get around this?

Comment: Where are you based because the site is not available outside the U.S.?

Comment: Try to update `User-Agent`. `Firefox/52.0` is really old.

Comment: Try using this header: `'{user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0'}`

Comment: @Sushil tried yours but same result..

Comment: @AndrejKesely I updated but same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `selenium`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

html = 'https://www.goodrx.com/classes'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(html)
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')

for a in soup.find_all('a',href=True):

    print ("Found the URL:",a['href'])

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
Found the URL: /classes?_pxhc=1604250381587
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005228506-Privacy-Policy
Found the URL: /
Found the URL: #a11y-content-start
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/how-goodrx-works
Found the URL: /discount-card
Found the URL: /discount-card
Found the URL: /mobile
Found the URL: /conditions
Found the URL: /pharmacy-near-me
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/blog/
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com
Found the URL: /my-rx/sign-in
Found the URL: /
Found the URL: #0-9
Found the URL: #a
Found the URL: #b
Found the URL: #c
Found the URL: #d
Found the URL: #e
Found the URL: #f
Found the URL: #g
Found the URL: #h
Found the URL: #i
Found the URL: #k
Found the URL: #l
Found the URL: #m
Found the URL: #n
Found the URL: #o
Found the URL: #p
Found the URL: #q
Found the URL: #r
Found the URL: #s
Found the URL: #t
Found the URL: #u
Found the URL: #v
Found the URL: #w
Found the URL: #x
Found the URL: /5-alpha-reductase-inhibitor-alpha-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /5-alpha-reductase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /5-lipoxygenase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /a2a-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /ace-inhibitor-calcium-channel-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /ace-inhibitor-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /ace-inhibitors
Found the URL: /acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /acetaminophens
Found the URL: /acetic-acid-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /acetic-acids
Found the URL: /acetylcholine-release-inhibitors
Found the URL: /acetylcholine-releasing-agents
Found the URL: /acl-inhibitor-cholesterol-absorption-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /acl-inhibitors
Found the URL: /adrenal-cytotoxic-agents
Found the URL: /adrenocorticotropic-hormones
Found the URL: /alcohol-antagonists
Found the URL: /aldosterone-antagonist-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /aldosterone-antagonists
Found the URL: /alkalinizing-agents
Found the URL: /alkylating-drugs
Found the URL: /alkylphosphocholine-drugs
Found the URL: /allergen-immunotherapies
Found the URL: /allylamine-antifungals
Found the URL: /alpha-agonist-beta-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /alpha-agonists
Found the URL: /alpha-blockers
Found the URL: /alpha-glucosidase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /alpha-hydroxy-acids
Found the URL: /aluminum-complexes
Found the URL: /aminoglycoside-polypeptide-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /aminoglycoside-antibiotic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /aminoglycoside-antibiotic-polypeptide-antibiotic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /aminoglycoside-antibiotics
Found the URL: /aminosalicylates
Found the URL: /amlyn-analogues
Found the URL: /ampa-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /anabolic-steroids
Found the URL: /androgen-receptor-inhibitors
Found the URL: /androgens
Found the URL: /angiotensin-receptor-neprilysin-inhibitors
Found the URL: /anthelminthics
Found the URL: /anthracyclines
Found the URL: /anti-anginals
Found the URL: /anti-epileptics
Found the URL: /anti-iges
Found the URL: /antiarrhythmics
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-alpha-agonist-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-antidiarrheal-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-barbiturate-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-benzodiazepine-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-beta-agonist-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergic-opioid-combinations
Found the URL: /anticholinergics
Found the URL: /anticoagulants
Found the URL: /antidiarrheals
Found the URL: /antiemetics
Found the URL: /antifibrinolytics
Found the URL: /antifolate-sulfa-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /antifolate-antibiotics
Found the URL: /antifolate-antimalarials
Found the URL: /antifolates
Found the URL: /antigas-drugs
Found the URL: /antihistamine-alpha-agonist-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-non-narcotic-antitussive-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-opioid-sudafed-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-opioid-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-sudafed-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamine-vitamin-b6-analogue-combinations
Found the URL: /antihistamines
Found the URL: /antimalarials
Found the URL: /antimetabolites
Found the URL: /antimycobacterials
Found the URL: /antiparasitics
Found the URL: /antiperspirants
Found the URL: /antiplatelet-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /antiplatelet-drugs
Found the URL: /antiprotozoal-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /antiprotozoals
Found the URL: /antipsoriatics
Found the URL: /antirheumatics
Found the URL: /antiseborrheics
Found the URL: /antisense-therapeutics
Found the URL: /antiseptics
Found the URL: /antithyroid-drugs
Found the URL: /apob-inhibitors
Found the URL: /arb-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /arb-thiazide-like-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /arbs
Found the URL: /aromatase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /arteriolar-vasodilator-nitrate-combinations
Found the URL: /arteriolar-vasodilators
Found the URL: /asparagine-specific-enzymes
Found the URL: /attachment-inhibitors
Found the URL: /atypical-antidepressants
Found the URL: /atypical-antipsychotic-ssri-combinations
Found the URL: /atypical-antipsychotics
Found the URL: /azapirones
Found the URL: /azole-antifungal-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /azole-antifungals
Found the URL: /barbiturate-acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /barbiturate-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /barbiturate-opioid-acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /barbiturate-opioid-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /barbiturates
Found the URL: /bcl2-inihibitors
Found the URL: /benzodiazepine-tricyclic-antidepressant-combinations
Found the URL: /benzodiazepines
Found the URL: /benzothiazoles
Found the URL: /benzylamine-antifungals
Found the URL: /beta-agonist-anticholinergic-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-agonist-anticholinergics-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-agonist-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-agonist-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-agonists
Found the URL: /beta-blocker-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-blocker-thiazide-like-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /beta-blockers
Found the URL: /beta-hydroxy-acids
Found the URL: /biguanides
Found the URL: /bile-acid-sequestrants
Found the URL: /bile-acids
Found the URL: /bisphosphonate-vitamin-d-combinations
Found the URL: /bisphosphonates
Found the URL: /blood-viscosity-reducers
Found the URL: /blys-specific-inhibitors
Found the URL: /bradykinin-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /c1-inhibitors
Found the URL: /calcimimetics
Found the URL: /calcitonins
Found the URL: /calcium-channel-blocker-ace-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /calcium-channel-blocker-arb-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /calcium-channel-blocker-arb-combinations
Found the URL: /calcium-channel-blocker-statin-combinations
Found the URL: /calcium-channel-blockers
Found the URL: /cannabinoids
Found the URL: /carbonic-anhydrase-inhibitor-alpha-agonist-combinations
Found the URL: /carbonic-anhydrase-inhibitor-beta-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /carbonic-anhydrase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /cardiac-glycosides
Found the URL: /carnitine-supplements
Found the URL: /catecholamine-depletors
Found the URL: /catecholamine-synthesis-inhibitors
Found the URL: /catecholamines
Found the URL: /ccr5-antagonists
Found the URL: /cd20-antibodies
Found the URL: /cd22-antibodies
Found the URL: /cd52-antibodies
Found the URL: /cd79b-antibodies
Found the URL: /central-alpha-agonist-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /central-alpha-agonist-thiazide-like-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /central-alpha-agonists
Found the URL: /central-nervous-system-depressants
Found the URL: /central-nervous-system-stimulants
Found the URL: /cephalosporin-antibiotic-beta-lactamase-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /cephalosporin-antibiotics
Found the URL: /cftr-potentiators
Found the URL: /cgrp-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /chemoprotectants
Found the URL: /chloride-channel-activators
Found the URL: /cholesterol-absorption-inhibitor-statin-combinations
Found the URL: /cholesterol-absorption-inhibitors
Found the URL: /cholinergic-agonists
Found the URL: /cholinesterase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /cmv-nucleoside-analogues
Found the URL: /cni-immunosuppressants
Found the URL: /coagulation-factors
Found the URL: /colchicum-alkaloids
Found the URL: /collagen-specific-enzymes
Found the URL: /complement-inhibitors
Found the URL: /comt-inhibitors
Found the URL: /conotoxins
Found the URL: /corticosteroid-keratolytic-combinations
Found the URL: /corticosteroid-retinoid-combination
Found the URL: /corticosteroid-vitamin-d-analogue-combinations
Found the URL: /corticosteroids
Found the URL: /cps-1-activator
Found the URL: /ctla-4-agonists
Found the URL: /ctla-4-antagonists
Found the URL: /cyclic-lipopeptide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /cyp17-inhibitors
Found the URL: /cystine-depleting-agents
Found the URL: /ddci-comt-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /ddcis
Found the URL: /decarboxylase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /demulcents
Found the URL: /dialysis-solutions
Found the URL: /dicarboxylic-acids
Found the URL: /dopamine-agonists
Found the URL: /dopamine-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /echinocandin-antifungals
Found the URL: /egfr-inhibitors
Found the URL: /endonuclease-inhibitor
Found the URL: /endothelin-antagonists
Found the URL: /enzyme-replacement-therapies
Found the URL: /ergot-derivatives
Found the URL: /erythroid-maturation-agents
Found the URL: /erythropoiesis-stimulating-agents
Found the URL: /estrogen-androgen-combinations
Found the URL: /estrogen-progestin-folate-combinations
Found the URL: /estrogen-progestin-iron-combinations
Found the URL: /estrogen-progestin-combinations
Found the URL: /estrogen-agonist-antagonists
Found the URL: /estrogens
Found the URL: /expectorant-non-narcotic-antitussive-combinations
Found the URL: /expectorant-opioid-sudafed-combinations
Found the URL: /expectorant-opioid-combinations
Found the URL: /expectorant-sudafed-combinations
Found the URL: /expectorants
Found the URL: /fatty-acids
Found the URL: /fibrates
Found the URL: /fluoride-supplements
Found the URL: /folate-analogues
Found the URL: /gaba-agonists
Found the URL: /gaba-analogues
Found the URL: /gc-c-agonists
Found the URL: /gcs-inhibitors
Found the URL: /gene-therapy-drugs
Found the URL: /glinide-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /glinides
Found the URL: /gliptin-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /gliptin-glitazone-combinations
Found the URL: /gliptins
Found the URL: /glitazone-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /glitazone-sulfonylurea-combinations
Found the URL: /glitazones
Found the URL: /glp-1-agonists
Found the URL: /glp-2-analogs
Found the URL: /glycopeptide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /glycosaminoglycans
Found the URL: /gonadotropin-releasing-hormone-agonist-estrogen-progestin-combinations
Found the URL: /gonadotropin-releasing-hormone-agonist-progestin-combinations
Found the URL: /gonadotropin-releasing-hormone-agonists
Found the URL: /gonadotropin-releasing-hormone-antagonists
Found the URL: /gonadotropins
Found the URL: /growth-hormone-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /growth-hormone-releasing-factors
Found the URL: /hdac-inhibitors
Found the URL: /hedgehog-pathway-inhibitors
Found the URL: /hepatitis-b-nrtis
Found the URL: /hepatitis-c-protease-ns5a-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /hepatitis-c-protease-nucleotide-polymerase-ns5a-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /hepatitis-c-protease-inhibitors
Found the URL: /her2-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /herpes-virus-nucleoside-analogue-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /herpes-virus-nucleoside-analogues
Found the URL: /histamine-2-antagonists
Found the URL: /histamine-3-antagonists-inverse-agonists
Found the URL: /hiv-entry-inhibitors
Found the URL: /hiv-integrase-strand-transfer-inhibitors
Found the URL: /hiv-nnrtis
Found the URL: /hiv-nrti-integrase-strand-transfer-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /hiv-nrti-nnrti-combinations
Found the URL: /hiv-nrtis
Found the URL: /hiv-protease-inhibitors
Found the URL: /human-alpha-1-proteinase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /human-immunoglobulin-gs
Found the URL: /human-platelet-derived-growth-factors
Found the URL: /hydroxypyridone-antifungals
Found the URL: /idh1-inhibitors
Found the URL: /idh2-inhibitors
Found the URL: /immune-response-modifiers
Found the URL: /influenza-a-inhibitors
Found the URL: /insulin-antagonists
Found the URL: /insulins
Found the URL: /integrin-antagonists
Found the URL: /interferon-alphas
Found the URL: /interferon-betas
Found the URL: /interferon-gammas
Found the URL: /interleukin-antagonists
Found the URL: /iron-supplements
Found the URL: /keratolytics
Found the URL: /ketolide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /kinase-inhibitor-prostaglandin-combinations
Found the URL: /kinase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /leptin-analogues
Found the URL: /leukocyte-growth-factors
Found the URL: /leukotriene-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /lfa-1-antagonists
Found the URL: /lincosamide-macrolide-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /lincosamide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /lipase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /local-anesthetic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /local-anesthetics
Found the URL: /long-acting-beta-agonists
Found the URL: /loop-diuretics
Found the URL: /lymphocyte-growth-factors
Found the URL: /macrolide-sulfa-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /macrolide-antibiotic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /macrolide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /magnesium-supplements
Found the URL: /maois
Found the URL: /mast-cell-stabilizers
Found the URL: /medical-foods
Found the URL: /medical-supplies-and-devices
Found the URL: /megakaryocyte-growth-factors
Found the URL: /melanin-synthesis-inhibitor-retinoid-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /melanin-synthesis-inhibitors
Found the URL: /melanocortin-receptor-agonists
Found the URL: /melatonin-receptor-agonists
Found the URL: /metal-chelators
Found the URL: /methylxanthine-expectorant-combinations
Found the URL: /methylxanthines
Found the URL: /microtubule-inhibitors
Found the URL: /monobactam-antibiotics
Found the URL: /monoclonal-antibodies
Found the URL: /mood-stabilizers
Found the URL: /msaas
Found the URL: /mtor-inhibitors
Found the URL: /mtp-inhibitors
Found the URL: /mucolytics
Found the URL: /multivitamin-and-mineral-supplements
Found the URL: /muscarinic-agonists
Found the URL: /muscarinic-antagonists
Found the URL: /muscle-relaxant-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /muscle-relaxant-opioid-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /muscle-relaxants
Found the URL: /neuraminidase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /nhe3-inhibitors
Found the URL: /nicotine-agonists
Found the URL: /nicotinic-acids
Found the URL: /nitrates
Found the URL: /nitrofuran-antibiotics
Found the URL: /nitroimidazole-tetracycline-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /nitroimidazole-antibiotics
Found the URL: /nk1-serotonin-antagonist-combinations
Found the URL: /nk1-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /nmda-receptor-antagonist-antiarrhythmic-combinations
Found the URL: /nmda-receptor-antagonist-cholinesterase-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /nmda-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /non-narcotic-antitussives
Found the URL: /nonselective-alpha-beta-blockers
Found the URL: /nrf2-activator
Found the URL: /nris
Found the URL: /ns5a-inhibitors
Found the URL: /nsaid-acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaid-calcium-channel-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaid-histamine-2-antagonist-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaid-prostaglandin-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaid-proton-pump-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaid-cough-and-cold-combinations
Found the URL: /nsaids
Found the URL: /nucleoside-analogue-antifungals
Found the URL: /nucleoside-analogue-antivirals
Found the URL: /nucleoside-metabolic-inhibitor-cytidine-deaminase-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /nucleoside-metabolic-inhibitors
Found the URL: /nucleotide-polymerase-ns5a-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /nucleotide-polymerase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /opioid-acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-anticholinergic-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-phenothiazine-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-sudafed-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-agonist-antagonists
Found the URL: /opioid-antagonist-atypical-antidepressant-combinations
Found the URL: /opioid-antagonists
Found the URL: /opioids
Found the URL: /orexin-receptor-antagonists
Found the URL: /orthopoxvirus-inhibitor
Found the URL: /osmotic-stimulant-laxative-combinations
Found the URL: /osmotic-laxatives
Found the URL: /oxaborole-antifungals
Found the URL: /oxazolidinone-antibiotics
Found the URL: /parathyroid-hormones
Found the URL: /parp-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pcsk9-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pd-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pde3-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pde4-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pde5-inhibitors
Found the URL: /pediculides
Found the URL: /penem-antibiotic-beta-lactamase-inhibitor-renal-dehydropeptidase-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /penem-antibiotics
Found the URL: /penicillin-antibiotic-beta-lactamase-inhibitor-combinations
Found the URL: /penicillin-antibiotics
Found the URL: /pet-medications
Found the URL: /phosphate-binders
Found the URL: /phosphate-supplements
Found the URL: /photoenhancers
Found the URL: /pituitary-hormones
Found the URL: /plasma-kallikrein-inhibitors
Found the URL: /platinum-based-drugs
Found the URL: /pleuromutilin-antibiotics
Found the URL: /podophyllotoxins
Found the URL: /polyene-antifungal-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /polyene-antifungals
Found the URL: /polypeptide-antifolate-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /polypeptide-antibiotics
Found the URL: /potassium-binders
Found the URL: /potassium-channel-blockers
Found the URL: /potassium-channel-openers
Found the URL: /potassium-salts
Found the URL: /potassium-sparing-diuretics
Found the URL: /progesterones
Found the URL: /progestin-agonist-antagonists
Found the URL: /progestin-antagonists
Found the URL: /progestins
Found the URL: /prostacyclin-agonists
Found the URL: /prostacyclines
Found the URL: /prostaglandin-e1-agonists
Found the URL: /prostaglandins
Found the URL: /proteasome-inhibitors
Found the URL: /proton-pump-inhibitor-penicillin-macrolide-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /proton-pump-inhibitor-penicillin-rifamycin-combinations
Found the URL: /proton-pump-inhibitors
Found the URL: /psoralens
Found the URL: /pyrethroids
Found the URL: /pyrimidine-synthesis-inhibitors
Found the URL: /quinolone-antibiotic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /quinolone-antibiotics
Found the URL: /radiopharmaceutical
Found the URL: /rankl-inhibitors
Found the URL: /recombinant-human-dnases
Found the URL: /recombinant-human-growth-hormones
Found the URL: /renin-inhibitor-arb-combinations
Found the URL: /renin-inhibitor-calcium-channel-blocker-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /renin-inhibitor-calcium-channel-blocker-combinations
Found the URL: /renin-inhibitor-thiazide-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /renin-inhibitors
Found the URL: /ret-inhibitors
Found the URL: /retinoid-lincosamide-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /retinoid-macrolide-antibiotic-combinations
Found the URL: /retinoids
Found the URL: /rifamycin-antimycobacterial-combinations
Found the URL: /rifamycins
Found the URL: /rna-splicing-modifiers
Found the URL: /rna-synthetase-inhibitor-antibiotics
Found the URL: /saline-laxatives
Found the URL: /selective-relaxant-binding-agents
Found the URL: /serotonin-agonist
Found the URL: /serotonin-antagonists
Found the URL: /sgc-stimulators
Found the URL: /sglt2-inhibitor-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /sglt2-inhibitor-gliptin-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /sglt2-inhibitor-gliptin-combinations
Found the URL: /sglt2-inhibitors
Found the URL: /short-acting-beta-agonists
Found the URL: /sickle-hemoglobin-polymerization-inhibitor
Found the URL: /sirnas
Found the URL: /skin-barrier-emollients
Found the URL: /snris
Found the URL: /somatostatin-analogues
Found the URL: /sphingosine-receptor-modulators
Found the URL: /ssias
Found the URL: /ssris
Found the URL: /statins
Found the URL: /steroidogenesis-inhibitors
Found the URL: /stimulant-laxatives
Found the URL: /stool-softener-stimulant-laxative-combinations
Found the URL: /stool-softener-laxatives
Found the URL: /streptogramin-antibiotics
Found the URL: /sulfa-antibiotic-corticosteroid-combinations
Found the URL: /sulfa-antibiotics
Found the URL: /sulfones
Found the URL: /sulfonylurea-biguanide-combinations
Found the URL: /sulfonylureas
Found the URL: /sympathomimetc-acetaminophen-combinations
Found the URL: /sympathomimetic-anti-epileptic-combinations
Found the URL: /sympathomimetic-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /sympathomimetics
Found the URL: /tetracycline-antibiotics
Found the URL: /thalidomides
Found the URL: /thiazide-potassium-sparing-diuretic-combinations
Found the URL: /thiazide-diuretics
Found the URL: /thiazide-like-diuretics
Found the URL: /thrombopoiesis-stimulating-agents
Found the URL: /thyroid-stimulating-hormones
Found the URL: /thyroxine-triiodothyronine-combinations
Found the URL: /thyroxines
Found the URL: /tnf-blockers
Found the URL: /topoisomerase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /tricyclic-antidepressants
Found the URL: /triiodothyronines
Found the URL: /triptan-nsaid-combinations
Found the URL: /triptans
Found the URL: /trpv1-agonists
Found the URL: /ttr-stabilizers
Found the URL: /tubulin-inhibitors
Found the URL: /typical-antipsychotic-tricyclic-antidepressant-combinations
Found the URL: /typical-antipsychotics
Found the URL: /urease-inhibitors
Found the URL: /uricosuric-colchicum-alkaloid-combinations
Found the URL: /uricosuric-drugs
Found the URL: /urinary-analgesics
Found the URL: /urinary-antibiotic-anticholinergic-combinations
Found the URL: /urinary-antibiotics
Found the URL: /vaccinations
Found the URL: /vaginal-ph-regulators
Found the URL: /vaptans
Found the URL: /vasopressins
Found the URL: /vegf-antibodies
Found the URL: /vinca-alkaloids
Found the URL: /viscosupplements
Found the URL: /vitamin-b12-analogues
Found the URL: /vitamin-d-analogues
Found the URL: /vitamin-k-supplements
Found the URL: /vmat-inhibitors
Found the URL: /wake-promoting-agents
Found the URL: /wound-dressings
Found the URL: /xanthine-oxidase-inhibitors
Found the URL: /xpo1-antagonists
Found the URL: /insurance
Found the URL: /mobile
Found the URL: /discount-card
Found the URL: /drugs
Found the URL: /conditions
Found the URL: /classes
Found the URL: /drug-guide
Found the URL: /pets
Found the URL: /brand
Found the URL: https://gold.goodrx.com/
Found the URL: https://heydoctor.goodrx.com
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/treatment
Found the URL: /how-goodrx-works
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/blog/
Found the URL: /pharmacy-near-me
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/healthcare-professionals
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/developer
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026530331-Advertising-on-GoodRx
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032961692-Accessibility-on-GoodRx
Found the URL: /about
Found the URL: https://www.goodrx.com/press
Found the URL: /social-impact
Found the URL: /jobs
Found the URL: https://investors.goodrx.com
Found the URL: https://gx9e.app.link/jHSgllC1o4
Found the URL: https://gx9e.app.link/tud54ux1o4
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005225563-Terms-of-Use
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005228506-Privacy-Policy
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005228506-Privacy-Policy
Found the URL: https://support.goodrx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005225563-Terms-of-Use
Found the URL: https://www.facebook.com/goodrx
Found the URL: https://www.instagram.com/goodrx
Found the URL: https://twitter.com/goodrx
Found the URL: http://legitscript.com/pharmacy/goodrx.com
Found the URL: https://www.safe.pharmacy/buying-safely/
Found the URL: http://www.bbb.org/losangelessiliconvalley/business-reviews/online-drug-and-prescription-services/goodrx-in-santa-monica-ca-351397#bbbseal
```